# scanning image and take text from it android

Tags: android, ocr

I have seen some applications that scan image and give back text. Is there any library for this or not? I mean either scanning text or taking a picture of it and identify characters?

I have searched for OCR but I have not found material so as to read. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at a library called [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). Here's [a tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use google vision library for convert image to text, it will give better output from image. 
Add below library in build gradle:

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.0+'

     TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

    Frame imageFrame = new Frame.Builder()

            .setBitmap(bitmap)                 // your image bitmap
            .build();

    String imageText = "";


    SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = textRecognizer.detect(imageFrame);

    for (int i = 0; i < textBlocks.size(); i++) {
        TextBlock textBlock = textBlocks.get(textBlocks.keyAt(i));
        imageText = textBlock.getValue();                   // return string
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And this library too: [Java OCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/) on sourceforge.